# Android appending additional headers

Tags: java, android, network-programming, http-headers, android-volley

When receiving a response from a volley request, the following headers are appended:

> X-Android-Received-Millis:1395544235409
>
> X-Android-Response-Source:NETWORK 200
>
> X-Android-Sent-Millis:1395544235363

According to Android Network Monitor tool, the above headers contribute to the data usage by the app and I was wondering if there's a way to prevent them from being appended to the response header?

Thanks

Comment: "According to Android Network Monitor tool, the above headers contribute to the data usage by the app" -- I believe that you are misinterpreting your analysis. Those are synthetic headers added locally on the device to the response. They would only contribute to data usage if they were actually coming from the server.

Comment: When i check the response size from the server on a web application, it amounts to 200 bytes,  however on my native android application the network monitor tool reads 500 bytes. The only difference between the responses retrieved on the web and native android app are the response headers mentioned above. Thoughts?

Comment: Those headers do not appear to combine to be 300 bytes. Moreover, again, they are not coming from your server, and therefore are not contributing to *actual* bandwidth consumption. I do not know how exactly Android Studio's network monitor tool performs its measurements. I would not expect these headers to be counted in there (since they are not coming in over a socket), but I cannot state that conclusively. I would look for other differences (e.g., the browser is asking for gzip responses, and your Android request is not).