# Android - Http library retrofit vs okhttp3

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

I wish to create an api for http requests on android. I used volley before, but it causes some problems about headers. It removes content-length from headers. It doesn't fit http standardization.

So I wish to try another library. Many users suggest Retrofit. But retrofit requires a model. In my case the model is not defined. Because I expect url, body, headers and method. I don't know the data. Retrofit is not a good choice for me. Am I right?

I think I should use okhttp3.

[Volley adds extra headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40306887/android-appending-additional-headers)

Comment: Retrofit doesn't require a model. Gson is only an *example* converter. And it actually uses Okhttp behind the scenes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902716/comparison-of-android-networking-libraries-okhttp-retrofit-and-volley

Comment: Retrofit is over OkHttp, so is more better.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, good choice. Go with okhttp3 library, I am using this library for past a year now. As you said it doesn't require any models and in addition to that it have regular updation, bug fix upgrades available... Got for it.